# Getting error in creating Schedule Query in Big Query

Tags: google-bigquery

I have linked my google analytics account with big query and trying to create a schedule in big query to get my desired output on regular basis, but while saving the schedule query the "Schedule query error" occurred. As this is something which I could not understand.

I want to run query multiple time so that I could get updated live report of my data.

Link shared for your reference.
[click here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/RJZnE.png)

Comment: There can be several resons for an error. Has the table to which the data is append the same schema? Did you try to write and replace to another table? The query itself runs without issues?

Comment: Yes, it has the table. yes I have created new table but still facing the same problem.

Comment: Are you using the correct region? I have had this error before and trying again later seemed to fix it..

Comment: Yes Jeremy, I am using correct region

Comment: You have the rights to create a schedule query? Could you please try following: create a new schedule query `select 123 as test` to a new table.

Comment: HI Samuel, I do have right to create a schedule query.  I have tried this but same error appeared again.

Comment: @AasifKhan Do you have the required permission to schedule a query? You can follow this [article](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/scheduling-queries#required_permissions) regarding the same. Let me know whether this is helpful or not.